# Quale connotazione può assumere la parola "asse" allorché sia usata in senso figurato?

Tags: grammar

Spesso sento parlare di *assi* che si formano fra individui e/o insiemi di individui e/o società commerciali e/o altri soggetti.

Prescindendo dall'ovvietà secondo la quale in relazione al contesto ogni parola può avere connotazioni negative, sapreste indicarmi se la parola *asse* assume preferibilmente una tale connotazione o meno?

Per esempio, si supponga di leggere su un giornale

> ... i partiti X e Y hanno formato un asse per la riforma della legge elettorale ...

dovrebbe il lettore pensare che il giornalista che ha scritto quella frase voglia gettare un'ombra sul rapporto fra i partiti X e Y? O, in alternativa, dovrebbe il lettore pensare che quell'asse possa produrre effetti favorevoli in ordine alla riforma *de quo*?

Answer (score 5):

Non c'è connotazione negativa.

In questo caso ***asse*** ha lo stesso significato letterale dell'inglese ***shaft*** (o ***axis***), ossia un elemento rigido che mette in contatto due strutture, causandone un movimento dipendente l'una dall'altra, come appunto l'asse tra due ruote.

In senso figurato significa che i due partiti si sono accordati e quindi "si muovono insieme", il che rappresenta un'informazione piuttosto neutrale.

L'informazione può assumere un connotato negativo (i due partiti si sono accordati per il loro tornaconto) o positiva (i due partiti stanno facilitando una decisione grazie al loro accordo), ma questo prescinde dall'utilizzo del termine ***asse***.

Senza ulteriore contesto è impossibile dire se la frase citata come esempio ha valore positivo, negativo o neutrale.

Comment: I think you mean "axis" not "shaft"

Comment: Both work :) https://www.google.com/search?q=shaft+mechanical&espv=210&es_sm=119&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=vCmEUowVz_DaBdqggLgF&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1676&bih=933

Answer (score 3):

L'asse per antonomasia è stato purtroppo quello Roma-Berlino, per questo motivo solitamente la parola asse, intesa come accordo, ha un'accezione se non negativa, di certo poco lusinghiera.

Parlando poi di partiti politici se X e Y sono su posizioni avverse per altre cose, un'asse per la legge elettorale può significare che quei due partiti si stanno accordando per il loro tornaconto. Altrimenti il giornalista avrebbe parlato più semplicemente di accordo.

Asse, almeno per me, mette in relazione due elementi distanti che si accordano per un vantaggio comune.

Comment: No, non sono d'accordo. L'informazione data è neutrale, e ciò che può renderla negativa o positiva prescinde dal termine usato.

Comment: Per me, ma non solo, asse nel senso di accordo si porta dietro una connotazione truce. Certo poi c'è anche l'asse stradale, ma una parola porta con sè anche la sua storia

Comment: Asse significa solamente essere compatti (in assetto) in merito a qualcosa. Per esempio in questo articolo (trovato su Google) https://www.facebook.com/PartitoFederalistaEuropeo/posts/450093935081228 si trova la frase "In questi giorni si è formato un vero e proprio "asse" Roma-Madrid; i due Paesi più grandi del Sud Europa (assieme fanno 105 milioni di abitanti) chiedono all'UE, soprattutto ai Paesi nordici (Berlino in primis), di aiutare i giovani europei disoccupati" che ha chiaramente un'accezione positiva.

Comment: Anche in questo contesto la parola asse è utilizzata per rappresentare un accordo in grado di dare più forza (a Roma e Madrid), in assetto come dici tu, ma sempre contrapposto a qualcuno o qualcosa. Altrimenti sarebbe stato semplicemente un accordo. L'asse richiama sempre un "nemico" a cui contrapporsi, la parola quindi per me non è di per sè negativa, ma ci si aspetta che chi faccia l'asse lo faccia per un motivo ben preciso.

Comment: contrapposto a qualcuno o qualcosa, non ha necessariamente significato negativo come suggerisce invece la tua risposta. Due parti che si alleano contro qualcosa di "male", ha anzi una connotazione positiva e rende onore alle parti in causa. Di nuovo, il termine in sé è neutrale e indica semplicemente un'intesa. Gli elementi per giudicarne la positività esulano dal termine stesso.

Comment: Quelli che formano un asse di solito sono i cattivi, gli alleati invece sono in buoni. Poi ci può essere l'alleanza dei satanisti assassini e l'asse degli angeli del focolare, se ti suonano un po' male vuol dire che asse e alleanza si portano dietro una connotazione che va al di là del significato letterale

Comment: Continuo a non essere d'accordo con l'interpretazione, mi dispiace, ma penso che ci siamo chiariti sulle rispettive posizioni.

Comment: A me in realtà non dà l'idea di qualcosa di *necessariamente* negativo, ma comunque rimane un senso "militareggiante" di fondo (e in genere se è contrapposto a degli "alleati" il giudizio di chi scrive è chiarissimo).

Comment: Anche io non sono d'accordo. C'è una forte distinzione fra *un asse* e *l'Asse*.

Comment: Si dice che la storia è scritta dai vincitori. Ma forse, anche la grammatica ;)